# Set Breakpoints in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using pyCharm for the first time today.  I'm running a very simple program and I'm trying to set a breakpoint.  I can't set a breakpoint no matter what I do, and it seems like almost everything under the Run menu is greyed out.  Is this feature disabled in the Community version of PyCharm?  This seems like a very desirable feature to have access to, but everything on my system seems to be shut off?  Even when I Google for solutions, I get lots of hits, but none of the recommendations actually works for me.  Any thoughts?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I see your file name is `Unnamed` so my guess is PyCharm is unable to decipher that it is a Python file. Could you try renaming it with the `.py` extension and then try?

Comment: Isn't there the option `Debug 'Unnamed'` ?

Comment: The file is as .txt , why:?

Comment: I see now that you're using a scratch file. Debugging scratch files is not supported as given [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207018015-Is-it-possible-to-debug-a-scratch-file-)

Comment: It's really astonishing how bad UI design can be. Why not just add a simple function in the menu to add a break point where the cursor is? OR, just include it into the context menu, where most people will look for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let Pycharm recognize your file as `.py` file, by editing filename to `scratch.py`.
There is highly chance that Pycharm doesn't recognize the file type, then it can't correctly configure an interpreter for it. If rename doesn't work, try to manually set the configuration, (in this pic is the dropdown arrow near `preprocess`)  [image: here]

Answer (score 9):

One caveat that caused me a lot of headache was that a breakpoint needs to be on a line with executable code.  I was trying to set a breakpoint on a blank line before the statement where I wanted to check a variable's value.  Everything was greyed out because the cursor was not on an executable line of code.  Move the cursor to the next executable line after the point where you want to check the state and try to set a breakpoint there.

Comment: thanks for this, lost so much time thinking pycharm was broken because I couldn't set breakpoints

Answer (score 0):

You can add the breakpoint by just clicking on the left hand side next to the line number. And then click on Run -> Debug Have you tried it already?[image: Check attached image]

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, in most IDEs, you can do exactly that.  This doesn't work for me.  When I try that, absolutely nothing happens.

Comment: I use the PyCharm community edition as well. There is no limitation on CE to debug for sure.

Comment: Can you place your cursor on the line that you want to add the breakpoint and press Cmd+F8 or Cntrl+F8?

Comment: I don't have a Cmd key; Ctrl+F8 does nothing at all.  Maybe something wasn't installed correctly.  I would think debugging is one of the most basic features in any modern IDE.  I don't know why that thing says 'Unnamed'.  I created a new scratch file and named it 'Scratch.txt'

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right.  Because it was a scratch file, it couldn't all the debugging features were disabled.  It would be nice to step through the code line by line; that doesn't seem to work.  It would be nice to see values passed into variable; even that's doesn't work for me.  The Spyder debugger isn't great, but at least you can print variables or dump data to a text file and figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

It is not that comfortable as the red dot, but you can add *breakpoint()*  to your code,but it will also stop in normal mode

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the pycharm will fix the issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).